# SQL Server 2000 on Windows 2008 Logon Account

Tags: windows, sql-server

I have managed to install SQL2000 on Windows 2008 (Fun!) but have a small issue I cannot figure out.

When starting the MSSQL$2000 service with a domain account, the service fails to start reporting:

```
Windows could not start the MSSQL$SQL2000 service on Local Computer.
Error 5: Access Denied.
```

Starting it with the Local Service account is fine, any idea on what the cause might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set permissions on some NTFS folders that are used by SQL Server.

The "Local Service" account has local admin rights therefore it works.

They lazy fix is to make the domain account local admin too, which IIRC is easiest for SQL Server 2000 (not needed for SQL Server 2005+). Or ensure that rights are granted on the SQL Server install folder + all paths used for MDFs, LDFs and error logs